# Functional analysis problems

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Problem**: Let $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3,...$ be non $-$ negative continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1x^k \psi_n(x)dx$$ exists for every $k=0,1,2,...$.Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f(x) \psi_n(x)dx$$ exists for every for every continuous function $f$ on $[0,1].$

Studying some functional analysis problems, and the problems in my problem sheet my professor gave us seem alittle too hard. This is actually one of our assignment problems, I really would appreciate some hints at least. Can anyone help me with this problem? Our professor gave us a hint and he said use Stone-Weierstrass theorem, then construct some sequence and show that it is Cauchy. Still have no clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $\lim \int_0^{1} \psi_n(t)\, dt$ exists so $C\equiv \sup_n \int_0^{1} \psi_n(t)\, dt <\infty$. Let $f$ be a continuous function and let us show that $\{\int f\psi_n\}$ is Cauchy. Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$. Then $$|\int f \psi_n -\int f\psi_m| \leq |\int p \psi_n -\int p\psi_m| +|\int f \psi_n -\int p\psi_n| +|\int f \psi_m -\int p\psi_m|$$ The second term is bounded by $\epsilon C$ and the last term is also bounded by the same number. The first term tends to $0$ as $n,m \to \infty$. Can you complete the proof now?

Comment: Is it then: $$||f-p||_{\infty}\int_0^1 \psi_n+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+||f-p||_{\infty}\int_0^1 \psi_m \le \frac{\epsilon}{3M}M+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+ \frac{\epsilon}{3M}M=\epsilon$$ Also shouldnt the first integral of the RHS in your answer be:$$\bigg|\int_0^1 f\psi_n-\int_0^1p\psi_n\bigg|$$

Comment: I think the RHS is correct.

Comment: Why is it:$$∣∫_0^1p\psi_n−∫_0^1p\psi_m\bigg|$$
In one of the terms on the RHS of your answer? I do not get this part sorry. I get everything else but this part of the inequality.

Comment: $\int f \psi_n -\int f \psi_m =(\int f\psi_n -\int p \psi_n) +(\int p \psi_n-\int p \psi_m)-(\int f \psi_m-\int p \psi_m)$

Comment: Thank you for this, it was very helpful !